# Take UISearchDisplayController full screen with UIView acting as UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am having a hard time adding a `UISearchDisplayController` to my app. The situation is this: The primary navigation in the app takes place by scrolling between `UITableViewControllers` whose table views are all subviews of a `UIScrollView`. Each of these has a `UISearchDisplayController` for searching the contents within each `UITableView`.

I also have a `UIView` outside of the `UIScrollView` which takes up the entire width of the screen and 85 pixels of the height, located at the very top of the interface. This acts as a kind of `UINavigationBar`, but due to the very custom nature of this element, I have made it a subclass of `UIView`.

My problem is that when you activate the `UISearchBar`, I want the "navigation bar" to move off the screen and the `UISearchBar` to take its place (like in the native Mail app where tapping the search field hides the navigation bar). It seems to me like I not only have to manually hide the "navigation bar" but also expand the size of the `UIScrollView` and all of its nested `UITableViews` in order to achieve this.

I am still a novice, so I am completely puzzled as to how to do this. Is there a simple solution or do I have to do this all manually and/or restructure my code in order to create the desired effect?